# Laravel middleware for admin or auth in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to laravel and don't know about laravel restriction mechanism, i have read about middleware but confused how to use it and why it is used and how this will works, so please guide me how i can implement it for restriction purposes i.e for auth, sa user routes.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make Sure your have role column or attribute in database users table.

**STEP 1**

Create a Midlleware

```
php artisan make:middleware AnyNameYouWant
```

it will create a nice boilerplate for you.

**STEP 2**

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (\Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
      return $next($request);
    }

      return redirect('home');
}
```

**STEP 3**

Use this in Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware::class,
```

];

**STEP 4**

Protect your routes.

```
Route::get('admin/profile', function () {
//
})->middleware('admin');
```

You are done

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn is straight from the Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware

or you can just watch a short Laracasts video: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch/episodes/14

Comment: would you like to tell me when should we use it and what are benefits of it

Comment: In a nutshell, middleware is used to perform any actions before the request hits your controller, especially if its an action that applies to multiple controllers/routes (e.g. authentication, CSRF tokens, etc.). Go through the docs and video. If you have any further questions, feel free to post them.