# Can not access the user register or login page while login as admin

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel auth and trying to access the user login and register page while I am login as admin. But i can not access, I think there must be some changes in guards and providers. please help
I have only one table where I have defined the admin separately. fig is given.[image]

[image: admin]

Above the pictures from user table where for admin I assign 1 and for all others users assign zero. I can login on both and redirected on seperate views for user and admin. but on same time I can not access both user and admin.

HomeController.php code is given.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Auth;
use DB;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
 public function allusers()
    {
        $key['key'] = DB::table('users')->get();
        return view('allusers',$key);
    }

}
```

Code of routes is given here.

```
Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web','auth']],function(){
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
    Route::get('/home', function(){
        if (Auth::user()->admin==0) {
            return view('home');
        }
        else {
            $users['users'] = \App\User::all();
            return view('adminhome', $users);
        }

    });
});
```

Please help what kind of changes I can do in guards and providers so I can access both on same time.

Comment: Did you get any error? please mention

Comment: Sir there is no error but I can not access the register and login page while already login as admin. I want to access the user login page, when I try to access register page, it is redirected to  home

Comment: I wrote the answer with the description, check it

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` you have a `__construct()` that checks if the user is guest then continue and you should change it

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
```

and you should change it like bellow to check that user is login

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Note: By this change just logged in user will access to the registration page you should customize the condition as you want.

have a view on this link for log as admin 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42473137/9246297

Comment: Thanks it works, but I want to give access only for admin to register a user. when I log in as user then I also can access register page and I dont want that.

Comment: then you should add your condition here

Comment: In register controller? or some where else I should write condition

Comment: I update the construct function, please check, in controller that I mention

Comment: Trying to get property 'admin' of non-object error is showing

Comment: Please follow this if you want to check the admin https://stackoverflow.com/a/42473137/9246297